# MoveIt Tutorial - All Links at the same place!

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS-Community,

I am currently working my way through the MoveIt-GettingStarted Tutorial (https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html).
I do have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS Melodic.

Everything works fine, until I try to add 'MotionPlanning' from the moveit_ros_visualization folder into my RViz.
All Links appear at the same place and it seems like there are no Joints loading.
I checked via rqt graph if my joint_state_publisher or my robot_state_publisher is not working. But regarding to rqt_graph both are actually working.

Any advice how I can fix that problem would be great.
Thansk alot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314233/moveit-tutorial---all-links-at-the-same-place!/) by [cluue](https://answers.ros.org/users/39748/cluue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you check whether this is another manifestation of the issue described in (among others) #q272692?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cluue](https://answers.ros.org/users/39748/cluue/) on 2019-01-30**:
Sadly it doesnt help me yet.

I get an output which says "No active joints or end effectors found for group 'hand'. Make sure that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace."

But actually i dont know how to fix it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-30**:
That's not really related. Ignore it for now.

What is the output of `echo $LC_NUMERIC`?

**Comment by [cluue](https://answers.ros.org/users/39748/cluue/) on 2019-01-30**:
The output of `echo $LC_NUMERIC` is en_US.UTF-8.

I did a mistake by not putting that to my .bashrc file. Now my joints work! Thanks a lot!